# RadDataGrid user editable only one column

Tags: c#, datagrid, uwp, telerik

My RadDataGrid control contains DataGridBooleanColumn column which should be editable and other columns are not editable, I have set property CanUserEdit="True" in DataGridBooleanColumn column, but the checkbox in that column still not editable. How to Edit only one column of RadDataGrid ?

Comment: Editable column is this - "<telerikgrid:DataGridBooleanColumn PropertyName="Select" Header="Select"  SizeMode="Auto" CanUserEdit="True"/>
"

Comment: Do you have an Edit Command Column?  How does your code differ from this demo?  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/automatic-crud-operations/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: @Seano666 this control is in ASP.net , my control is in windows UWP.

Answer (score 0):

We should be able to set the `UserEditMode` property of `RadDataGrid` to `Inline`. The default value of `UserEditMode` is `None` that the editing is not allowed.

If you want edit only one column of `RadDataGrid`, you should be able to set `CanUserEdit`for other column to `False`. The default value of `CanUserEdit` is `True`.

For example:

```
<telerikGrid:RadDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" UserEditMode="Inline">
    <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns >
        <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Product" Header="Product" CanUserEdit="False"/>
        <telerikGrid:DataGridBooleanColumn PropertyName="Stock" Header="Stock" CanUserEdit="True" />
    </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
</telerikGrid:RadDataGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    ObservableCollection<Data> Products;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Products = new ObservableCollection<Data>()
        {
         new Data { Product = "Milk", Stock = true },
         new Data { Product = "Cheese", Stock = false },
         new Data { Product = "Bread", Stock = false },
         new Data { Product = "Chocolate", Stock = true }
        };
        this.DataContext = Products;
    }
}
public class Data
{
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public bool Stock { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help,as I dont want to use this alternative ,i tried this solution earlier before also,but user has to double click on that row then and then only user is able to change the selection, I want user to select once only on boolean column to edit that value. please help on that.